# Azure App Service: After receiving 2 transient errors has response spikes for 5-10 min

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have Azure App Service that works as WEB API for my flutter app.
Overall response times are OK, but after service receives few transient (usually more than 1) errors it almost stops working for about 5-10 min.
Transient errors usually are followed by task canceled errors and underline provider failed to open.

How can I avoid transient errors?
How can I recover after transient errors?
Will it be better to move my service on AWS?

I have App Service S1
Code first Database S0

[image: Average Response time]

On screen u can see response times, every spike is made by transient errors.

[image: Errors]

Here u can see Errors

[image: Requests]

Requests on service

[image: Database DTU%]

DTU Usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed problem!
Problem was connected with high RAM usage.

What I did:

- Set Debug to false in web config
- Made sure that DbContext disposes after controller method
- Made private static HttpClient, to use only one HttpClient instance in whole api
- Optimized methods, that made many round trips to Database, to make single call to Database

Now my response times are less than 1s.